# Relative Connectionstring Browsing

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, database-connection, connection-string

For a application, I need a relative Connectionstring that I can also run the application on other computers.

So I searched a lot how to realise that an found the following:

```
con.ConnectionString =
"Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;" +
"User Instance=true;" +
"User Id=UserName;" +
"Password=Secret;" +
"AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|DBName.mdf;";
```

This is the `bin/debug` folder. My database is in `bin/debug/Datenbank` folder. So I tried:

```
"AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Datenbank\\FarmersCalc.mdf;";
```

and

```
 "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Datenbank\\FarmersCalc.mdf;";
```

but it didn´t work.

How can I fix that?

**EDIT:**
I edit it because I am not qualified to answer my question.

Ok, I´ve got the answer: The structure of my connectionstring was wrong.

Here´s the solution:

```
string connectionstr = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;" + "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Datenbank\\DBNAME.mdf;" + "Integrated Security=True;" + "User Instance=true;";
```

Comment: what error is it showing you?

Comment: `ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.` ... For sure, I´ve opened the connection

Comment: then you dont have the appropriate rights to open that folder. Run as an admin and try again!

Comment: No, then it is the same error...